# problems importing scanner class

Tags: java

I am trying to execute the following code but keep getting this error:

> Error: Main method not found in class ScannerDemo, please define the main method as:
>      `public static void main(String[] args)`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ScannerDemo
public class Main {

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userName;

        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        username = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("your number is" + username + "enter your next number");
        username2 = sc.nextline();
        System.out.println("your total is" + username2 );     
    }
}
```

I think I must be importing the Scanner class wrong, I have tried different methods but nothing has worked for me yet.

Answer (score 4):

You have two class declarations in a row at the top! This is wrong. Your import is fine. Try:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ScannerDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: yep that did it. thanks for that. now the rest of my code is a mess of errors, but I am working on that. Thanks Jonathon

Answer (score 3):

Your class definition is wrong. You are trying to define two classes, `ScannerDemo` and `Main`. Replace:

```
class ScannerDemo
 public class Main
```

With just:

```
public class ScannerDemo
```

Also, in your `main` method, you should be referring to the `userName` variable, instead of `username`, and you are not defining `username2`. Note that Java identifiers *are* case sensitive:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a number");
  String userName = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println("your number is" + username + "enter your next number");
  String username2 = sc.nextline();
  System.out.println("your total is" + username2 );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerDemo {

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userName;

        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        username = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("your number is" + username + "enter your next number");
        username2 = sc.nextline();
        System.out.println("your total is" + username2 );     
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ScannerDemo {

      public static void main (String [] args) {

         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         String userName;

         System.out.println("Enter a number");
         int userName = sc.nextInt();
         System.out.println("your number is " + userName);
         System.out.println("enter your next number");
         int userName2 = sc.nextInt();
         System.out.println("your total is " + (userName2 + userName));     
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This adds nothing new. Comment on an existing answer if something needs to be modified.

Answer (score -3):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ScannerDemo {

public static void main (String [] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userName;

        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int username = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("your number is " + username);
        System.out.println("enter your next number");
        int username2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("your total is " + (username2 + username));     
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to add some explanation to your answer so the reader can understand it, or know why it is the best answer to this question. You can do that by pressing the "`edit`" button below the answer.